# Override JdbcUtils`saveTable` method

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

How to extend the spark-jdbc sink and override `saveTable` method, i wanted to use one transaction for the entire dataframe batch instead of separate transactions per partitions.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L656